# How to add specific vite config file in cypress config file

Tags: vuejs3, cypress, vite

I want to start cypress with a specific file ( vite.config.test.js)

**My stack**

1. vue: 3.2.47
2. Cypress: 13.2.0
3. vite-cypress: 1.4.2

**structure of the project**

/src => containt vue file

/cypress => containt  cypress file for testing

package.json

vite.config.js

vite.config.test.js

cypress.config.js

**File cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
module.exports = defineConfig({
    component: {
        devServer: {
            framework: "vue",
            bundler: "vite",
        },
        indexHtmlFile: 'cypress/support/component-index.html',
        fixturesFolder: "cypress/fixtures",
        specPattern: "cypress/integration",
        supportFile: "cypress/support/index.js",
        slowTestThreshold: 10000,
        folders: {
            downloadsFolder: 'cypress/downloads',
            fixturesFolder: 'cypress/fixtures',
            screenshotsFolder: 'cypress/screenshots',
            videosFolder: 'cypress/videos',
            pageLoadTimeout: 100000,
        }
    },
})
```

**file vite.config.test.js  => file for testing only**

```js
export default defineConfig((params) => {
    const {mode} = params
    console.log('defineConfig TEST')
})
```

**File vite.config.js => file for dev only**

```js
export default defineConfig((params) => {
    const {mode} = params
    console.log('defineConfig DEV', params)
  
})
```

**My command**
`./node_modules/.bin/cypress open --component --config-file cypress.config.js`

My command start only the fie vite.config.js

I try many solutions but it's not work

**Solution 1:**
File cypress.config.js

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
module.exports = defineConfig({
    component: {
       setupNodeEvents(on) {
            on(
                'file:preprocessor',
                vitePreprocessor({
                    configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'vite.config.test.js'),
                    mode: 'development',
                }),
            )
        },
       devServer: {...}
        ...
     
})
```

Not work ... it launch vite.config.js

**Solution 2**
File cypress.config.js

```js
devServer: {
            framework: "vue",
            bundler: "vite",
            // optionally pass in vite config
            viteConfig: require('./vite.config.test.js')
           
        },

Error :  Your configFile is invalid: project/cypress.config.js
This error concerns the line viteConfig
```

I just want to read the config test file

Comment: Are you was able to figure out? I think have similar issue cypress doesn't want to parse vue file. I assume it's just not applying vite configs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the vite config parameters and use them in a test, you can add it via `env` tag

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const viteConfig = require('./vite.config.test.js')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  env: {
    viteConfig,
  },
  component: {
    ...
```

In the test

```js
const viteConfig = Cypress.env('viteConfig')
```

Generally, `env: {...}` settings can take any keys but other config keys are pre-defined.